# Understanding the definition of a language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Could you please help me understand the following Language

$L = \{ a | a ∈ \{0, 1\}^∗, |a| = k ≥ 4, a = a_1a_2...a_{k−1}a_k, ∃i ∈ N, 1 ≤ i < k : a_i = a_{i+1} \}$
what does $a_i = a_{i+1}$ mean? Could you please give me an example of word in $L$?

Comment: It means exercise 3 b, I should have removed it

Comment: `I should have removed it` Don't muse, do: [edit your question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/136287/edit).

Comment: (Dubious: $0000$, useful: $0010$, not $0101$: argue *why*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "$a_i = a_{i+1}$" means "$a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ are equal".

Presumably $a_i$ is a symbol, that is, $a_i \in \{0,1\}$. Therefore the condition states that $a$ contains at least four symbols, and there are two adjacent symbols which are equal, that is $a$ contains either $00$ or $11$ as a substring. Stated differently, $a$ contains at least four symbols and it doesn't consist of alternating zeroes and ones (i.e. you are not allowing 0101, 01010, ... or 1010, 10101, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I understand it correctly, is for example 010110 a valid word?

Comment: Yes, that's a word in the language.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down

$\{\; a \mid a ∈ \{0, 1\}^∗$ $\quad$
a language of words over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$

$|a| = k ≥ 4$ $\quad$ with length $k$ at least $4$

$a = a_1a_2...a_{k−1}a_k$  $\quad$ lets call the symbols of $a$ with indices $a_1$ to $a_k$  $\quad$

(this is a little implicit here, but OK)

$\exists i \in N$, $1 ≤ i < k$  $\quad$ there exists a natural number $i$, a position in the string $a$,

$a_i = a_{i+1} \; \}$  $\quad$ such that the two consecutive letters $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please give an example of such a word?

Comment: Please have a look at the answer by @Yuval. He is quite clear in that part, so I do not feel I need to repeat it. (By accident we answered within 8 seconds or so.)